# Using apacheDS for unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, ldap, apacheds

I have an application that uses a LDAP server, and I need to write some unit tests. I started mocking LDAP DirContext and others, but it makes too difficult for my current tests,
so I thought I using an embedded LDAP server.

This link does not work:
http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/1.5/42-using-apacheds-for-unit-tests.html
-> Embedding ApacheDS - Conference Materials -> Code Examples (requires Maven 2.x) (SVN)

Does anyone have the code example for it or any alternative to ApacheDS?

Answer (score 13):

Instead of mocking, use the in-memory directory server provided by the UnboundID LDAP SDK. This is a fully-fledged server and its use will result in realistic responses from a directory server, which will lead to more complete testing and more robust code.

#### see also

- [Using the in-memory directory server](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/ldap-in-memory-directory-server-using-unboundid-ldap-sdk/)
- [The UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.ldap.com/unboundid-ldap-sdk-for-java)

Comment: thanks for the info; i'll try a bit more with ApacheDS, and otherwise i'll turn to the one you mention.

Comment: after viewing @Terry's answer and blog i ended up creating this:  https://github.com/trevershick/ldap-test-utils .  It's what i use now to do in memory ldap testing. UnboundID is great.

Comment: Note that the original poster was asking specifically about using ApacheDS in Unit Tests, not UnboundID.